# BotBuilder, Direct Line API returns "tokenParameters is missing User" with Enhanced authentication options

Tags: node.js, json, botframework, bearer-token, direct-line-botframework

I have a bot published on an Azure account, from which I'm trying to take the magic code out, so following the [Direct Line documentation](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/09/01/using-webchat-with-azure-bot-services-authentication/) I improved the code to hide the token. But once the Enhanced authentication options are enabled I always get the same response.

```js
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadArgument",
    "message": "tokenParameters is missing User."
  }
}
```

And I am not able to figure out how to complete the HTTP Request with the user data.

The bot is based on BotFramework SDK v4, plus some controllers for requesting and refreshing the token using the encapsulted secret key.
I added *userId* data to the request by different and wrong ways getting always the same result.

**Requesting token code**

```js
server.post('/dl/tokenRequest', async (_, res) => {
  try {
    const userId = "dl_testuser1";
    const askToken = await fetch('https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate', {
      headers: {
        authorization: Bearer ${ process.env.DIRECT_LINE_SECRET }
      },
      //HERE THE userId INFORMATION,
      method: 'POST'
    });
    const json = await askToken.json();
    if ('error' in json) {
      console.log('Requesting token - Error');
      res.send(500);
    } else {
      console.log(`Requesting token ` + json.token);
      res.send(json);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.send(500);
  }
});
```

How should I put the user's information to obtain an OK from the DL API as I received before enabling the Enhanced tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the `Content-Type` in your header. Take a look at the code snippet below.

```
try {
  const res = await fetch('https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate', 
    { 
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer <SECRET>`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: {
        user: { 
          id: "dl_123", // user id must start with 'dl_'
          name: "user" 
        }
      }
    });

    const json = await res.json();

} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}
```

Note, you shouldn't have to check is 'error' is in the JSON response - the try-catch block should take care of that.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @tdurnford. Yes, it helped! But I have still to deal with the magic code. I thought It will desappear once the Enhaced option are enabaled. So, is there any step I forgot? I'm using the OAuthPrompt dialog.

Comment: Glad you found it helpful. If you wouldn't mind accepting my answer, I would appreciate it. In terms of your follow up question, I think you're going to have to open another StackOverflow question. There are too many details to answer in the comments.

Comment: @JonJS Have you opened and got answered regarding your follow up question about magic code?

Comment: @dchang
It Kinda Works. So I tested the above method with a userID starting in "dl_", once I enabled Enhanced authentication options and added the url where the bot was hosted as a trusted origin (you could add localhost if you are testing using your local server) it didn't require me to use the magic code any more. After authenticating with AzureAD via the Oauth Card in the bot. I refreshed the page and I was logged in. No magic code required. I might have to change my bot logic to get rid of the need to refresh the page, but other than that it works fine.

Comment: @AliAkram, yes, we also already put it to work. It seems, for some reason, one needs to regenerate the directline secret key. We done it and it started to work. Thanks