# How to fix issue of HTML page for Web Chat Bot developed in C# using SDK V4 template is not opening in IE 11 browser?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, botframework, chatbot

The issue I am facing is I have developed a web chat bot with multiple waterfall dialog's using C# and bot framework V4 and deployed to azure successfully using Visual studio 2019 without any errors with it an HTML file to access the web channel chat bot. This HTML URL gets opened in all the browsers except IE 11 i.e. it works fine in:

1. Chrome
2. Edge
3. Firefox

But when comes to IE 11 it throws error and the chat bot never opens. Some times error like syntax error in JavaScript used in the HTML and so on so forth.

Now, my query is:

How to write or prepare the HTML script file which can work in all type of browsers? How to identify the browser dynamically and call the related script based upon that automatically.

I am using the below HTML file to access my chat bot after publishing in Chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>Web Chat: Custom style options</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!--
      For demonstration purposes, we are using the development branch of Web Chat at "/master/webchat.js".
      When you are using Web Chat for production, you should use the latest stable release at "/latest/webchat.js",
      or lock down on a specific version with the following format: "/4.1.0/webchat.js".
    -->
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%
        }

        body {
            margin: 0
        }

        #webchat {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="webchat" role="main"></div>
    <script>
        (async function () {
            // In this demo, we are using Direct Line token from MockBot.
            // To talk to your bot, you should use the token exchanged using your Direct Line secret.
            // You should never put the Direct Line secret in the browser or client app.
            // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-authentication

            // Token is found by going to Azure Portal > Your Web App Bot > Channels > Web Chat - Edit > Secret Keys - Show
            // It looks something like this: pD*********xI.8ZbgTHof3GL_nM5***********aggt5qLOBrigZ8
            const token = 'LxTsWrNC****bPm5awq3DW7hfb*************I2s0nb19f76Xdmm8';

            // You can modify the style set by providing a limited set of style options
            const styleOptions = {
                botAvatarImage: 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/v4sdk/media/logo_bot.svg?view=azure-bot-service-4.0',
                botAvatarInitials: 'BF',
                userAvatarImage: 'https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/45868722?s=96&v=4',
                userAvatarInitials: 'WC',
                bubbleBackground: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, .1)',
                bubbleFromUserBackground: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, .1)'
            };

            // We are using a customized store to add hooks to connect event
            const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
                if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
                    // When we receive DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED action, we will send an event activity using WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT
                    dispatch({
                        type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
                        payload: {
                            name: 'webchat/join',
                            value: { language: window.navigator.language }
                        }
                    });
                }
                return next(action);
            });

            window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
                directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }),
                styleOptions,store,
                webSpeechPonyfillFactory: window.WebChat.createBrowserWebSpeechPonyfillFactory()

            }, document.getElementById('webchat'));

            document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
        })().catch(err => console.error(err));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the same single HTML file to work for IE 11 also how to detect the browser and related script too fire automatically such that it works automatically.

I request you to please provide required modifications step by step in detailed guide manner as I am new to coding, BOT, HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

I did some Googling around it and they said to remove async function for IE use then.

I have also replaced the below line:

```
<script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
```

With the following:

```
<script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat-es5.js"></script>
```

But again it throws error at below part not sure how to solve this for which I couldn't get any proper answer:

```
const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, ({
      dispatch
    }) => next => action => {
      if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
        // When we receive DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED action, we will send an event activity using WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT
        dispatch({
          type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
          payload: {
            name: 'webchat/join',
            value: {
              language: window.navigator.language
            }
          }
        });
      }
```

**Expected Result:**

I want my HTML to open in all browsers and the HTML should contain the code for automatically detect browser and execute related script such that the chat bot opens in all browsers and functions properly without taking any additional time.

**Actual Result:**

Currently, chat bot not working in IE 11 but working in all other browsers.

---

Date: 7-June-2019

@tdurnford:
Please find my modified HTML script according to the sample provided below:

As tried to explain in my comment, I am not using Token generator instead the easy method provided in the below link and also the BOT is not loading until unless put I-FRAME which i get is wrong way of doing it according to below link:

The reason for not using token generator is also given in the below post itself.

[[BotFramework]: Is there a way to Display Oauth prompt in hero card or Adaptive card in a BOT Developed using SDK V4 in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56305535/botframework-is-there-a-way-to-display-oauth-prompt-in-hero-card-or-adaptive)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>Web Chat: Full-featured bundle with ES5 polyfills</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!--
      For demonstration purposes, we are using the development branch of Web Chat at "/master/webchat.js".
      When you are using Web Chat for production, you should use the latest stable release at "/latest/webchat.js",
      or lock down on a specific version with the following format: "/4.1.0/webchat.js".
    -->
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat-es5.js"></script>
    <style>
      html, body { height: 100% }
      body { margin: 0 }
      #webchat {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="webchat" role="main">

    </div>
    <script>
        (function (){
         const token = '<<Secret Code>>';

         const styleOptions = {
                botAvatarImage: 'Ur Image URL',
                botAvatarInitials: 'BF',
                userAvatarImage: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTXFpBTkKBW7JgYuePzhVoGkDDdZLVKQMZDbgy6j3C0sWvkkH1-',
                userAvatarInitials: 'WC',
                bubbleBackground: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, .1)',
                bubbleFromUserBackground: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, .1)'
            };

        var store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, function (_ref) {
                    var dispatch = _ref.dispatch;
                     return function (next) {
          return function (action) {
              if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
                  dispatch({
                      type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
                      payload: {
                          name: 'webchat/join',
                          value: { language: window.navigator.language }
                      }
                  });
              }

              return next(action);
                     };
                 };
             });

         window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
         directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
         token: token,
         styleOptions: styleOptions,
         store: store,
             webSpeechPonyfillFactory: window.WebChat.createBrowserWebSpeechPonyfillFactory()
        })}, document.getElementById('webchat'));           
          document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

can you please verify whether i have done anything wrong in the above script as i have tired to put all the correct values as needed everywhere as per my understanding/knowledge?

Can you please help me resolve the issue of BOT not opening in IE-11? if possible we can have a Skype connect to share screen and discuss it if needed on need basis based on mutually agreeable time.

Thanks & Regards
-ChaitanyaNG

Comment: You are using version ES6 javascript code: async, arrow functions etc. IE11 does NOT support ES6. So you have to rewrite everything using ES5 javascript or transpile the code into ES5 compatible code + polyfill the mising parts. Babel.js is the most used transpiler afaik and it should be easily added to visual studio if it isn't included yet.

Comment: Drop the `async`, replace arrow functions with standard function declarations, and surround your code with a `try`-`catch` rather than using the promise `.catch` (as the function will no longer return a promise).

Comment: Also doublecheck that the webchat.js library is IE11 compatible or use a version of it that is.

Comment: @Chaitanya N G I hope you got it working! If you feel my answer was sufficient, please "accept" it so I can clear this ticket from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help! Thanks

Comment: @tdurnford: Please give me some time will try to implement all the suggestions and then come back with my findings and take appropriate action accordingly.

Comment: @tdurnford: i have updated my queries and findings in original post due to comments limitation. can you please provide help me in resolving the above issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the async/await protocol in IE 11. Also make sure you are you using the es5 bundle. Take a look at this [Getting Started wit es5 Bundle](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/01.b.getting-started-es5-bundle) Web Chat Sample.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>Web Chat: Full-featured bundle with ES5 polyfills</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!--
      For demonstration purposes, we are using the development branch of Web Chat at "/master/webchat.js".
      When you are using Web Chat for production, you should use the latest stable release at "/latest/webchat.js",
      or lock down on a specific version with the following format: "/4.1.0/webchat.js".
    -->
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat-es5.js"></script>
    <style>
      html, body { height: 100% }
      body { margin: 0 }
      #webchat {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="webchat" role="main">

    </div>
    <script>
      const token = '<WEB_CHAT_SECRET>';

      const styleOptions = {
            botAvatarImage: 'Ur Image URL',
            botAvatarInitials: 'BF',
            userAvatarImage: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTXFpBTkKBW7JgYuePzhVoGkDDdZLVKQMZDbgy6j3C0sWvkkH1-',
            userAvatarInitials: 'WC',
            bubbleBackground: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, .1)',
            bubbleFromUserBackground: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, .1)'
        };

      const store = window.WebChat.createStore(
        {}, 
        function (_ref) {
          const dispatch = _ref.dispatch;
            return function (next) {
              return function (action) {
                  if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
                      dispatch({
                          type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
                          payload: {
                            name: 'webchat/join',
                            value: { language: window.navigator.language }
                          }
                      });
                  }
                  return next(action);
                };
            };
        });

        window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
          directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token: token}),
          styleOptions: styleOptions,
          store: store,
          webSpeechPonyfillFactory: window.WebChat.createBrowserWebSpeechPonyfillFactory()
        }, document.getElementById('webchat'));           
        document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have tried to create an HTML file to open my chat bot using above given link and script but then i am unable to load the bot in browser.
Long story short: I am not using Token generator otherwise i am directly giving my token value in the script as suggested in the below link:

which is working for chrome and others now, when i change the script according to above given sample the bot is not loading at all until unless i provide the I-FRAME tag value which according again above post is not the correct way of doing it. Find my updated HTML given in original post. Please help.

Comment: You do not need to wrap your Web Chat logic in a function since you are not using the async/await protocol. I've updated my answer to be more complete. You should only have to add your Web Chat secret. Also note you were passing things like style options and the custom store to DirectLine and not WebChat. I also correct that issue in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, it has resolved my issue thanks for all the help and your time as always.